# Zoom do browser não funciona com meu CSS

Tags: html, css

Tenho dentro da tag body 3 divs com altura definida em pixels e largura em porcentagem.
Quando a pessoa digita <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> os navegadores dão zoom até 500%.

O meu problema é que o zoom não funciona.

Tentei definir, na tag body e nos 3 ids definidos nas 3 divs: topo, corpo e rodapé.
No meu caso eu defini o `overflow-y` como `scroll` e as divs com `min-width` e `width` de `100` e `max-width` de `500%` porém não está resolvendo.

```
<body>
    <div id="todo">
        <div id="topo"></div>
        <div id="corpo">
        </div>
        <div id="rodape"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
/* 
    Created on : 31/05/2014, 23:25:56
    Author     : willian
*/

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500%;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#todo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

#topo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 200px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 500%;
    background: #fefcda;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
#corpo {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    height: 800px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 500%;
    background: #faf9ed;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
#rodape {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    height: 300px;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 500%;
    background: #fefcda;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: Posso perguntar qual a intenção do seu código? Eu sei o problema que você quer resolver, mas tem algumas coisas no seu CSS que eu não entendi. OBS: O zoom funcionou normalmente aqui: Chrome Version 34.0.1847.137

Answer (score 3):

Via CSS não tens controlo sobre a capacidade do navegador fazer ou deixar de fazer ampliação da página.

Esse tipo de indicações são passadas aos navegadores por meio de META TAGS colocadas na secção `<head></head>` onde podemos dar instruções do género:

```html
<meta name='viewport'
      content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' />
```

Aqui sim, podes indicar que a página começa à escala de 1 e o máximo até onde pode ir é 1, desabilitando assim a função de *zoom* no navegador.

**Nota:**

```
user-scalable=0  (não deixa o utilizador fazer zoom)
user-scalable=1  (deixa o utilizador fazer zoom)
```